# Tableau: 100% Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-chart

I am new to Tableau, and would like to create a 100% stacked bar chart like in Excel. I managed to stack the 2 different measures into a bar, but I can't get the % right. For the calculated field, I used "Percent of Total" and "Table (down)" but I get 100% for each measure. Refer to image.

[100% Stacked Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pbxx.jpg)

What I want is Citizen as a % of the sum of Citizen + Permanent. Specifically,
Citizen / (Citizen + Permanent)

How do I get it in Tableau? Thank you.

Note that this Qn is also posted at
https://community.tableau.com/message/860213#860213

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Quick Table Calculation" and then "Percent of Total"

then use the "Compute Using"

Select correct dimensions.